# How to create multiple python file and import them in a single python file in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am developing a game with kivy which has different levels, each level has it own python kivy file. I am using screen manager to move from one screen level to another. The problem is how do I import those python Kivy file containing each level inside the main.py file with kivy. Am not using .kv file.

```
# level1.py

import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import Floatlayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.label import Label 


class Level1(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Level1, self).__init__(**kwargs)

         
        self.btn1=Button(text='level 1', size_hint=(0.5, 0.5), 
        on_press=self.click_b1))
      
     self.add_widget(self.btn1)
        
             
           
        def click_b1(self, instance):
             pass
       
class Level1App(App):
    def build(self):
        return Level1()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Level1App().run()
```

```
# level2.py

import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import Floatlayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.label import Label 


class Level2(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Level2, self).__init__(**kwargs)

         
        self.btn1=Button(text='level 2', size_hint=(0.5, 0.5), 
        on_press=self.click_b1))
      
     self.add_widget(self.btn1)
        
             
           
        def click_b1(self, instance):
             pass
       
class Level2App(App):
    def build(self):
        return Level1()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Level2App().run()
```

How do I import level1.py and level2.py inside the main.py which has the screen manager(without .kv)

```
# main.py with screen manager 

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScreenManagement, self).__init__(**kwargs)


class Level1Window(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Level1Window, self).__init__(**kwargs)

# run level1.py file here
        

class level2Window(Screen):
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super(Level2Window, self).__init__(**kwargs)
            
# run level2.py file here

class Application(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManagement(transition=FadeTransition())
        sm.add_widget(Level1Window(name='#'))
        sm.add_widget(Level2Window(name='#'))
        return sm


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Application().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're running Application(App) class for your main game. Because of that, i never call diffrent .py files under screens. So i suggest you to code your game Screen classes below.Because you need it.For an example, if you need score after player pass to nextlevel , you can send your current score.Screen manager have useful functions:

**on_pre_enter**(before load page)  ,**on_enter**(after load page), **on_leave** and **on_pre_leave**.

So you just need to give *name* and *id* to your pages.Code when you want to send score and other values below **on_pre_leave** or **on_leave** functions. And switch page like:

```
self.manager.current = 'page2name'
```

Get values from previous page with **on_enter** or **on_pre_enter** func.:

```
score = self.manager.ids.page1id.score
```

If there is a diffrent short way, i hope to learn but i think this is the best and fastest way to code'em.